# Printing contents of an associative array to a file in bash

Tags: shell-script, shell

I need to print the contents of my associative array to a file in bash.. The console output printing is working fine but when I try to print it to a file, only one element is getting printed. Here is my code

```
 for KEY in "${!SYMBOLICLINK[@]}"; do
    printf "$KEY --> ${SYMBOLICLINK[$KEY]}" > /tmp/symlinks.txt
     # Print the KEY value
     echo " $KEY --> ${SYMBOLICLINK[$KEY]}"
      done
```

Can someone pls tell me what i am missing here

I also went through this

[BASH associative array printing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366581/bash-associative-array-printing)

but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where it's not working for you:

```
printf "$KEY --> ${SYMBOLICLINK[$KEY]}" > /tmp/symlinks.txt
```

The `>` redirection overwrites the file. You want `>>`, to append.

Overall, I would write your code like this, to improve safety, readability and performance:

```
for KEY in "${!SYMBOLICLINK[@]}"; do
    printf "%s --> %s\n" "$KEY" "${SYMBOLICLINK[$KEY]}"
done | tee /tmp/symlinks.txt
```

Reasons:

- More concise: get rid of the redundant string and save running two commands per iteration
- [`printf` is superior to `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819)